# How to delete a row in a section?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, row

My TableView contains multiple sections. Now when I click "delete" for the row selected, it deleted the row in upper section. How to fix this?

I guess the Index for the row to delete in not correct, but I am not sure and have no idea how to fix it. This is my code:

```
var sectionTitles = [String]()

var savedURLs = [[String]]()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {

            savedURLs.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(savedURLs, forKey: Key_SavedURLs)

            savingTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: `savedURLs[indexPath.section].removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)`

Comment: Eric, thank you. Please also see my comments below and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSIndexPath identifies both the row as well as the section of the cell. You need to check the `indexPath.section` and the `indexPath.row` to know which item in your `savedURLs` was deleted.

Comment: Thanks. I understand the logic and have revised. But it still deletes the url in upper section. Please see all codes below regarding the tableview. Thanks. Because it is too long I will paste in two commnets.                func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return savedURLs.count
    }
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        
        return sectionTitles[section]
        
    }

Comment: Part 2:            func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        return savedURLs[section].count
    }
    
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SavingCell")
        
        cell?.textLabel!.text = savedURLs[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        
        return cell!
    }

Comment: Dear All, I will post a new question with all codes for easy reading and please help.